# Blank question bodies in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Version 1.0.58

When viewing questions that contain multiple code blocks, the question is blank for a few screens. Answers and comments are OK.

I tried clearing application data, and rebooting they phone, no change. Mobile sites work perfectly.

Example: [What is the correct way to set up sw RAID1 so either drive boots?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188459/43525)

[image]
[image]

Also, now that I posted the pictures and links, this question also went blank

Comment: Any links to samples?

Comment: @deer hunter posted link and screenshot (didn't know I could from the phone)

Comment: Does editing the images out bring it back?

Comment: @Tim no change, editing images back out

Comment: I had this experience too: my question went blank after I added a single picture.

Comment: hmm okay. We will have to wait for Devs I suppose

Comment: can you use web inspector on mobile? It appears to me (from your images) that the app is not showing the `<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">` element

Comment: @Tim works great on the browser, but I don't know how to bring up dev tools on the android app

Comment: @martjinpieters I don't think so. My issue is questions are blank, never answers