# Blank questions and answers in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

This seems to be a result of a recent update of the Android app: certain questions and answers, such as both the question and the answer in [Why this system is not linear and how that influences the number of solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180098/why-this-system-is-not-linear-and-how-that-influences-the-number-of-solutions), show a box with the username, score, etc., but no content inside the box.

Sometimes the content is visible for a moment then disappears. This has happened in one other case as well, but I don't have a link to it, because I was hoping it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: @Martijn ironically, I'm on the android app now and that question has the problem.

Comment: Also reported here: [Blank question bodies in Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250707)

Comment: Also happens for that one. There must be evil afoot.

Comment: Reported by me here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250752/some-questions-are-not-visible